# ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseClass' from partially initialized module 'utilities.BaseClass' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

test_add_items file:

```
from time import sleep
from pageobject.BucketPage import BucketPage
from pageobject.Header import Header
# from pageobject.HomePage import HomePage
# from pageobject.LoginPage import LoginPage
from pageobject.MenuPage import MenuPage
from pageobject.PaymentMethodPage import PaymentMethodPage
# from testcases.test_login import TestLogin
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass


class Testitem(BaseClass):
    def test_add_items(self):
        # self.Generic_login()
        menupage = MenuPage(self.driver)
        bucketpage = BucketPage(self.driver)
        header = Header(self.driver)
        payment_method_page = PaymentMethodPage(self.driver)
        header.click_sidenavbar()
        header.click_explore_menu_sidenav()
        self.verifyPresence(menupage.Cards)
        Items = menupage.getCards()
        for item in Items:
            item_name = menupage.getItemName(item)
            if item_name == "Krunch Burger":
                menupage.clickAddToBucket(item)
                break
        #select pickup store
        self.verifyClickable(header.ModalPickup)
        header.click_modal_pickup().click()
        print("Pickup clicked")
        self.verifyPresence(header.VerifyPickupModal)
        self.verifyClickable(header.GetDirections)
        header.sendkey_modal_pickup_input().send_keys("test")
        header.select_pickup_store()
        self.verifyClickable(header.StartYourOrderModal)
        header.click_StartYourOrderModal()
        # make order using JazzCash
        menupage.clickViewBucket()
        self.verifyPresence(bucketpage.CheckoutButton)
        bucketpage.click_checkout_button()
        self.verifyPresence(payment_method_page.SelectPaymentModeButton)
        payment_method_page.click_select_payment_mode_button()
        self.SelectPaymentMode("Online Payment")


                
        sleep(5)

        sizes = len(Items)
        print(f"number of Items are {sizes}")
```

BaseClass file:

```
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from TestData.LoginData import LoginData

from pageobject.HomePage import HomePage
from pageobject.LoginPage import LoginPage
from pageobject.MenuPage import MenuPage
from pageobject.PaymentMethodPage import PaymentMethodPage
from testcases.test_login import TestLogin

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseClass:
    @pytest.fixture(params=LoginData.test_login_data)
    def getData(request):
          return request.param
    
    @pytest.fixture(params=LoginData.test_social_login_data)
    def getSocialData(request):
          return request.param
    
    def verifyPresence(self, path):
         WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(path)
            )
         
    def verifyOTP(self, path):
         WebDriverWait(self.driver, 90).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(path)
            )
         
    def closePopup(self):
     homepage = HomePage(self.driver)
     try:
          self.verifyPresence(homepage.CloseButton)
          homepage.Close_Button().click()
     except:
         print("Close")

    def verifyInvisibility(self,path):
         WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
              EC.invisibility_of_element_located(path)
              )
    def verifyClickable(self,path):
          WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
              EC.element_to_be_clickable(path)
              )
          
    def wait_for_toast(self, path):
          try:
            toast = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(path)
        )
            return toast.text
          except:
               return None
          
    def SelectPaymentMode(self, mode):
        payment_method_page = PaymentMethodPage(self.driver)
        self.verifyPresence(payment_method_page.SelectPaymentRadioBoxes)
        PaymentMethods = payment_method_page.get_select_payment_radio_boxes()
        for PaymentMethod in PaymentMethods:
            if PaymentMethod.get_attribute("value") == mode:
                return PaymentMethod.click()
            
    def Generic_login(self):
         homepage = HomePage(self.driver)
         loginpage = LoginPage(self.driver)
         menupage = MenuPage(self.driver)
         if not hasattr(BaseClass, 'actions_done'):
            self.closePopup()
            homepage.ClickLogin()
            BaseClass.actions_done = True
         loginpage.getNumber().send_keys(self.getData[2]["phone"])
         loginpage.clickLoginButton().click()
         self.verifyOTP(menupage.ViewBucket)
```

When i run add items testcase, BaseClass is not importing due to Circular import. How can I resolve this error?  It's working fine before creating Generic_login() function is BaseClass. But after i got error, I remove function but nothing happen

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the full error message (starting from "Traceback (most recent call last):")?